# Thymeleaf Passing a value from a text input to a controller in Spring Boot (Without Form Submission)

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this Text input and a button in a Thymeleaf HTML file:

```
<input type="number"/>
<btn><a th:href="@{/filter/{minimumAmount}}">Search</a></btn>
```

I want to pass the Integer value from the input and pass it to a controller after a click the Button.  In the input how do i reference the "minimumAmount" so that the value can be sent to the controller that will take the value and use it to run some custom query?

Here's my Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/filter/{minimum}")
    public String customList(Model model, @PathVariable int minimum){
        int total = expService.calculateTotalExpense(expenseRepo.customQuery(minimum));
        model.addAttribute("expenselist", expenseRepo.customQuery(minimum));
        model.addAttribute("totalExpense", total);
        return "expense";
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to send number as the minimumAmount?

Comment: yes, an integer value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<input type="number" id="amount"/>
<input type="hidden" id="minAmount" th:value="${minimumAmount}" />
<btn id="search">Search</btn>
```

jQuery

```
        $('#search').unbind("click");
    $('#search').bind("click",function(){
         var amount = $('#number').val();
           var minAmount = $('#minAmount').val();

          if(amount ===0){
             amount = minAmount; 
          }

        $.ajax({
          url: "filter/"+amount ,
          type: "get", //send it through get method,
          success: function(response) {
            //Do Something
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
          }
        });

});
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. However, I was looking for the Thymeleaf way to do it without using JavaScript.  Thanks anyways

Comment: Then the best way is using form submission which is not interested by you :)